# Casting a float into byte array of the float's integer value

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point, int, byte

I have tried with:

```
float f = 1.0f; // float with an integer value

unsigned char const * p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>(static_cast<uint32_t>(f));

// Debugging output:
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(float); ++i)
{
    std::printf("The byte #%zu is 0x%02X\n", i, p[i]);
}
```

Which prints no output.

Also with a straight reinterpret of the float:

```
unsigned char const * p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>(&f);
```

Which prints out its byte value, but not its "integer byte value" (I expect it to output `{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01}`).

How should I go about casting a float (which stores an integer value) to a byte array of the float's integer value, **hopefully without adding variables to the code**?

---

With the use of an extra variable I can get it to work by first static casting the float into an uint32_t:

```
uint32_t a = static_cast<uint32_t>(f);
```

And than reinterpret casting the address of the static cast's variable to a byte array:

```
unsigned char const * p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>(&a);
```

Comment: That's impossible. Where do you expect the bytes of the integer value to be if you don't add a variable to store them?

Comment: In a sort of temporary memory I guess, or a temporary variable created by the compiler automatically to allow this conversion. Though I do understand know why that might be impossible with the current compiler as a result of what you've said.

Comment: A temporary has a limited lifetime, so you couldn't take a pointer to one and use it in a later statement. You could bind it to a reference (extending its lifetime to match the reference, and effectively creating an extra variable) or pass it by reference to a function. But you can't take the address of a temporary.